# How to set the width of Swimlanes in PlantUML activity diagram?

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

I am using PlantUML to draw a activity diagram and I am using the new activity diagram syntax (beta).

I am not able to set the width of the swimlanes. I have tried using the following

```
skinparam swimlaneWidth 400
```

and

```
skinparam swimlaneWidth same
```

but these do not work. I have attached a sample diagram that shows the problem.

using

```
skinparam wrapWidth 100
```

I have been able to control when the activity text wraps to the next line, but that does not help with the swimlane width.

How do I set the width of the swimlanes? Happy to use a workaround if one exists.

Here is the full sample.

```
@startuml
skinparam wrapWidth 100
|Swimlane1|
start
:foo1;
|#AntiqueWhite|Swimlane2|
:foo2;
:Long Activity Name;
|Swimlane1|
:Very Very Very Long Activity Name;
|Swimlane2|
:foo5;
stop
@enduml
```

and the image this generates

[image: sample activity diagram].

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: set spaces in the title of the swimlane. Doing this it is only possible to enlarge it, not to shrink it.